# Unit testing MOCHA SINON CHAI (check call nested functions)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon-chai

If anyone understands the tests, please tell me how I can implement test for two things:

1)  Was obj.newRing method called, when makeRing function starts.
2) whether the parameter 'num' is passed to the function makeRing(*num*) is Matches with the property of the object passed in obj.newRing ({*number: num*}).

```
function makeRing (num) {
currRing = obj.newRing ({number: num});
 }
```

Maybe someone will have some ideas how to use sinon or else in this situation, I will be glad of any information. I suffer for a long time ... All thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to `obj` in your test, you can do the following:

```
// create a spy for your function:
const newRingSpy = sinon.spy();

// replace the real function with the spy:
sinon.stub(obj, 'newRing', newRingSpy);

// run the test:
makeRing(7);

// 1) validate that obj.newRing was called exactly once:
expect(newRingSpy.calledOnce).to.be(true);

// 2) and/or validate the arguments it was called with:
expect(newRingSpy.firstCall.args).to.eql([{number: 7}]);
```

If you just want to know whether the function was called at all, then this is already covered with the second check (if the function was not called, `newRingSpy.firstCall` is null).

In case you do not have access to `obj`, it might be the best strategy to change your production code to something like this:

```
function makeRing (num, obj) {
    currRing = obj.newRing ({number: num});
}
```

Then you can easily pass the stubbed `obj` to `makeRing()` in your test.

Comment: what if test does not have access to obj ? how to solve then ?

Comment: @ajayv I've updated my answer; does this answer your question?